# I want to add a hotspot to certain parts of the obj extension model I have installed with three.js. how can I do it?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can add a click event to the model I loaded with Three.js, but I can't add a click event to a particular part of the model I've uploaded. For example, I can make a click event on the car model I have installed, but what I want to do is exactly this: when I click on the wheel of the car I want to write 'wheel' to the console. When I click on the glass I want to write 'glass'.

How can I do it?

```
const objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader2();
objLoader.loadMtl('bugatti.mtl', null, (materials) => {
  objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
  objLoader.load('bugatti.obj', (event) => {
    const root = event.detail.loaderRootNode;
    scene.add(root);
    myModel = root;
       const domEvents = new THREEx.DomEvents(camera, renderer.domElement)

    domEvents.addEventListener(myModel, 'click', event => {
        console.log("car");
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to solve this issue during the design phase and ensure that your model does consist of multiple independent meshes grouped together to a more complex object. In this way, it will be much easier to select single components in `three.js` (and any other 3D engine).

Comment: So instead of designing the model as a whole,
design in pieces, combine on scene.

Comment: Well, the idea is to create child/parent relationships already in the DCC tool. Read for example the following documentation of Blender which explains this topic really well: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/relations/parents.html

Comment: Notice that you should use `glTF` instead of `OBJ` since the latter one does not support object hierarchies. Moreover, `glTF` is the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. More information right here: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models